# Using vim autoformat with markdown documents

Tags: vim, markdown

After some trial and error I have arrived at the following configuration as the best one for editing Markdown files in Vim with hard breaks:

```
setlocal formatoptions=tacqw
setlocal textwidth=80
setlocal wrapmargin=0
setlocal autoindent
```

This automatically reflows paragraphs with hard breaks, and it works well with bulleted lists as well.

Here's the rub: `fo=w` allows you to mark a line so that it does *not* get reflowed by not including trailing spaces. This works very well in all cases except when you want to get a `<br>` in Markdown because the syntax for that is to include two trailing spaces.

Is there any way for me to configure vim so that I get nice hard breaks with reflowing, but where reflowing is disabled when I've got two trailing spaces?

Or alternatively, is there a way to get Markdown to treat a line that *does not* end with whitespace as a line break?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here is my own solution to this. Not very elegant, but whatever works:

I just decided that I'd use the Vim convention (NoSpaceAtEnd==LineBreak), but send all my markdown through sed before compiling it (I do it in a script, so it's not that much extra work). Basically, sed appends two spaces to any line that ends in no space (leaving lines ending in one space untouched):

```
cat  "${input}"                 \
    | sed "s/\([^ ]\)$/\1  /"   \
    > "${input}.preprocessed"

pandoc -f markdown -t html -s --ascii   \
    -i "${input}.preprocessed"          \
    -o "${input}.html"
```

This could also be piped directly to pandoc to avoid generating a temporary file, but since it is the temporary file that is correct markdown, rather than my original file, I thought it would be handy to have that around if I need to paste it somewhere rather than run it through pandoc.

I'd still very much appreciate, accept, and upvote any alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This feature might have come after you asked your question but in Pandoc's extended version of Markdown you can escape newlines with `\`. So if you put a backslash at the end of a line you will get a `<br>`-tag there when converting to HTML. For example:

```
This paragraph\
will have hard line breaks\
when converted to another format with Pandoc.
```

This is according to the Pandoc manual which says that all characters [can be escaped](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#backslash-escapes) in Pandoc's version of Markdown.

If you want to stick to original Markdown and not Pandoc's extended version (and if you know you're just going to convert to HTML) you could just put the `<br>`-tag directly in the Markdown file because Markdown supports [inline HTML](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html). Like this:

```
This paragraph <br>
will have hard line breaks<br>
when converted to HTML.
```